# JS: setting on click via innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

```
function dungeonGen() {
    mapMenuDiv.innerHTML = ""
    for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        for (var y = 1; y < 6; y++) {
            genRoll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
            if (genRoll > 2) {
                mapMenuDiv.innerHTML += '<div id="s' 
                + i + 'b' + y + '"  style="width: 50px; height: 50px; left: ' 
                + 50 * (y - 1) + 'px; top:  ' + 50 * (i - 1) + 'px; position: absolute;"><img src=' + mapBL1Img + ' onclick=roomNormal></img></div>'
            }
            if (genRoll === 1) {
                mapMenuDiv.innerHTML += '<div id="s' + i + 'b' + y 
                + '"  style="width: 50px; height: 50px; left: ' + 50 * (y - 1) 
                + 'px; top:  ' + 50 * (i - 1) + 'px; position: absolute;"><img src=' + mapBL2Img + ' onclick=roomNormal></img></div>'
            }
            if (genRoll === 2) {
                mapMenuDiv.innerHTML += '<div id="s' + i + 'b' + y 
                + '"  style="width: 50px; height: 50px; left: ' + 50 * (y - 1) + 'px; top:  ' + 50 * (i - 1) + 'px; position: absolute;"><img src=' + mapBL3Img + ' onclick=roomNoGem></img></div>'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tried using onClick, onclick and onclick javascript:roomNormal. Still, nothing happens on image click.

Comment: Have you tried like `onclick="roomNoGem()"`?

Comment: Images are self-closing tags. Why not add a class and then add the event _in JavaScript_? It's less error prone, more reliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for

```
<img src="' + mapBL2Img + '" onclick="roomNormal()" />
```

Which calls a javascript **function** called roomNormal

Comment: "javascript:" is a total waste

Comment: It just labels the code as javascript, but good point, you should only need this for href's. I thought that IE actually used that identifier?

Comment: Oh, im dumb. Thanks! Used to setting it in js like img.onclick=function and now this didnt worked!